# Non Repeating Table Footer That Avoids Breaking Over Printed Pages CSS

Tags: html, css, printing, printing-web-page

So I have a weird situation were I have a table footer that I only need to repeat once so I decided to just add the "footer" `trs` to the end of the `tbody` so it would only appear once at the end of the table and look like a footer without the repeating on each printed page.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr><td>@item.Name</td></tr>
            <tr><td>@item.Total</td></tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>@Model.Items.Sum(x  => x.Total)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Discount</td>
            <td>@(Model.Items.Sum(x => x.Total) / 50)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This was fine until `Model.Items` had enough rows that it pushed the second row of the footer onto the next page when I need to keep the two footer rows together.

I've also tried using the actual `tfoot` tag like so with a `page-break-inside:avoid` style.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr><td>@item.Name</td></tr>
            <tr><td>@item.Total</td></tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>@Model.Items.Sum(x => x.Total)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Discount</td>
            <td>@(Model.Items.Sum(x => x.Total) / 50)</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

This kept the footer together but its now repeating on each page instead of once. Someone on another Stack Overflow question suggested using the following style on the `tfoot` to stop it repeating which worked, but now it ignores the `page-break-inside:avoid` style.

```
<tfoot style="display: table-row-group"></tfoot>
```

Does anyone know how to get a footer to appear once and avoid breaking over multiple printed pages?

Comment: If this question is related to printing you may want to add that tag, otherwise perhaps you can clarify what we're referring to as “pages”.

Comment: @coreyward yeah its referring to printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working but I had to apply a few styles to make it looks like one table. I put the original footer HTML into a `tr > td > table` like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr><td>@item.Name</td></tr>
            <tr><td>@item.Total</td></tr>
        }

        <tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>@Model.Items.Sum(x => x.Total)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>@(Model.Items.Sum(x => x.Total) / 50)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This allowed the footer to stay together while only appearing once at the end of the page.